# How to make Bootstrap 4 Hamburger Menu Work?

Tags: bootstrap-4, responsive-design, progressive-web-apps, hamburger-menu

Here's my 1st attempt at a PWA:
[Freight Class Calculator](https://flowster.app/calculators/freight-class-calculator/)

I can't figure out why the hamburger menu isn't working. When you click it, nothing happens, but there's also **no console errors** so it's difficult to debug.

[image]

Here's the code:

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand logo" href="https://flowster.app/">
            <img src="img/Flowster-Logo-v2-WP-266x90.png" alt="Flowster">
        </a>        
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="https://flowster.app/blog/">Blog</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="https://in.flowster.app/login">Log In</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item sign-up">
                <a class="nav-link" href="https://in.flowster.app/pricing">Sign Up</a>
                </li>            
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks so much!

Comment: From what I can see, you never included bootstrap.js file in your HTML. Like it says here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#js

Comment: @Amir5000 doh! That was obvious - thank you so much!

Comment: I'll make that the answer for you then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, you never included bootstrap.js file in your HTML. Like it says here getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#js